# How can I attach house numbers to stucco?

Tags: waterproofing, stucco

I live in the hot and humid Southeast US, but our house has some stucco on the front. Poor sealing have led to two major repairs (by previous owners) on this house that we know of, so I'm pretty paranoid.

I have house numbers and want to attach them to the house. They screw in. Normally this would be easy, but I'm really really nervous about drilling into the stucco. Am I right to be nervous? Or will the screw keep out any moisture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same issue.  Didn't want to drill through the stucco to mount house numbers.

I used [polyurethane caulk](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Vulkem-116-10-1-fl-oz-White-Paintable-Advanced-Sealant-Caulk/3595612?cm_mmc=shp-_-b-_-prd-_-pnt-_-ggl-_-LIA_PNT_000_PRO-_-3595612-_-local-_-0-_-0&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiAsIGrBhAAEiwAEzMlC7K6Ni8bP98nhwx-a4Pfz3srEc_KgBAG0zomalA_4lgtRZO9mrrWDBoCcc8QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds). It is very sticky, and can be painted if too much squeezes out past the edges.

I applied it to the back of the numbers and held them in place with blue tape. It dries in about 5 hours.